# Cross Validation - How it works

Tags: cross-validation

Requesting you to help that how 5-fold cross-validation works when selecting between 3 different parameter values of a parameter?

How many models are trained on subset of training set? Will it be 15 models, 5 models, 3 models or anything else?

Will the model be evaluated on testing set or on portion of training set?

Comment: Hello — you have proposed an idiosyncratic example. I expect you’d be better off reading one or more standard introductions to cross-validation.